# ReceiveTimeoutTransportException When searching while bulk insertion

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I get that error that says failed to get node info,  ReceiveTimeoutTransportException and timed out after [5000ms]] when I search in elasticsearch while a bulk insertion using java api is running.
What can I do towards that problem? I can't insert and search at the sametime without that exception being thrown.

Error Log:

```
org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$SimpleNodeSampler doSample
INFO: [Beyonder] failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9302}, disconnecting...
ReceiveTimeoutTransportException[[][127.0.0.1:9302][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness] request_id [26169] timed out after [5000ms]]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:696)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You can increase the timeout (so you give more time to your requests before timing out) or scale up your cluster (so you have more processing power to process searches and bulk calls at the same time). You should also try to make your bulk calls smaller, as apparently, your cluster could be too weak to process all you're throwing at it at once.